# How to to understand the homology groups $H_*(\Omega_0^\infty S^\infty)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stable-homotopy, algebraic-k-theory

The original statement of the Barratt--Priddy theorem says there is an isomorphism of homology groups
$$H_*(\Sigma_\infty)\cong H_*(\Omega_0^\infty S^\infty),$$
where $\Omega_0^\infty S^\infty$ is the component of the basepoint in $\Omega^\infty S^\infty$. The Barratt--Priddy--Quillen theorem strengthens this to a homotopy equivalence between the $+$-construction $B\Sigma_\infty^+$ and $\Omega_0^\infty S^\infty$. It follows that the stable homotopy groups of spheres are isomorphic to the homotopy groups of $B\Sigma_\infty^+$, which can be thought of as the algebric $K$-groups of finite sets.

The striking part of this latter statement is that it gives an equivalence between two objects that are interesting in their own right: the $K$-theory of finite sets and the stable homotopy groups of spheres. I'm wondering if there is a similar interpretation of the homology equivalence. The groups $H_*(\Sigma_\infty)$ are certainly interesting as the stable homology of symmetric groups, but it's less clear how to understand the groups $H_*(\Omega_0^\infty S^\infty)$. The Barratt--Priddy theorem gives us one answer, but my question is: is there a purely topological interpretation of these groups?

If we forget the restriction to the basepoint component, these groups are the integral homology groups of the infinite loop space $\Sigma^\infty\Omega^\infty\mathbb S$ of the sphere spectrum. So, I'm equivalently curious about the what significance of the spectrum $H\mathbb Z \wedge \Sigma^\infty\Omega^\infty\mathbb S$ is, if there is any.

Comment: Have you looked at the paper of Dyer and Lashof which describes the homology group you are asking about. Also work of Cohen-May-Lada is a classical reference. Certainly the infinite loop space of the sphere spectrum is still a very important object to study.